# Gradle multiproject tests not getting invoked

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, testng, build.gradle

I have a project having subprojects in the following structure

```
|-- project1
|   -- src
       --main
         --java
         -- resources
         -- test
|-- project2
    ..
|-- build.gradle
|-- gradle.properties
|-- settings.gradle
|-- weblogic.gradle
```

For project1, I have some test cases written in TestNG which are not getting invoked.

Here is by build script

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'ear'
apply plugin: 'java'
...
project(':project1') {
    ...
    dependencies{
        ...
        compile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.8'
        compile 'com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.3.2'
    }
    test{
        useTestNG()
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    }
    ...
}

project(':project2') {
    ..
}
...
```

The tests are working when tried from an IDE. Also the build script works for other tasks like build and deploy. Only test is failing.
Another observation was that when defining dependency, the test jars are getting downloaded only when i say compile. It doesnt download for testCompile.

When i execute

> gradle test

It says Build Succesful. But I dont see any test output on terminal nor report getting generated

Gradle version used is 2.0

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hello @rajesh, what exactly is failing? You got error from `gradlew check`? Paste it please

Comment: @pgregory , sorry I have edited the post to add that info

Comment: Maybe your tests are in up-to-date status, try to add `test.dependsOn cleanTest`

Comment: tried that. didnt work

Comment: How does settings.gradle look like? Have you included all the projects here?

Comment: yes, the project builds without issues. Only the tests arent working

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with my directory structure of the test code. I had put test under main. Figured this when i ran gradle test with -i switch.